# Is there a way to start org-mode agenda with a custom search?

Tags: org-agenda

I would like to start an org-mode agenda with a custom tag search (rather than starting the agenda and then doing the search).

The overall goal is to make a work and a personal agenda.  I can make the custom search commands easily enough:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("p" tags "-work")
        ("w" tags "+work")))
```

Normally I get to an agenda with a function like:

```
(defun just-agenda()
  (org-agenda-list)
  (delete-other-windows))
```

Is there a way to pass a custom search to the agenda when I call `org-agenda-list`?  I've seen a bunch of things that seem close in the docs but it feels like I'm missing something for how to do it.

Comment: Yes, type `C-h f` (aka `M-x describe-function`) and look at the arguments to `org-agenda-list` ....  Then, try setting up a test using the arguments ...  In addition, you can let-bind certain values potentially used by `org-agenda-list` ...  To see what makes it tick, type `M-x find-function` ....  Keep in mind that that there are also functions used for searches such as `org-tags-view` and `org-search-view`.

Comment: You can also use your custom searches with `(org-agenda nil "p")`.

Comment: Thanks!  `(org-agenda nil "p")` did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: The `describe-function` tip was also useful (although I should have thought to do that one myself).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use your custom searches programmatically with:

```
(org-agenda nil "p")
```

In this example `p` is the key of your custom command you want to invoke.

The documentation for the function is unfortunately missing any hint about its `ORG-KEYS` parameter:

```lisp
(org-agenda &optional ARG ORG-KEYS RESTRICTION)
```