# How to call a custom agenda command?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

In org-mode, I have a custom agenda set with:

```el
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("d" "todo"
               agenda ""
               ((org-agenda-span 1)
        (org-agenda-start-day "-0d")
                (org-agenda-start-with-log-mode '(closed))
        ))
    ))
```

I can call it with `C-c a d`.

I want to call it programmatically. The documentation offers passing an argument:

> (org-agenda &optional ARG ORG-KEYS RESTRICTION)
>
> Dispatch agenda commands to collect entries to the agenda buffer.
> Prompts for a command to execute.  Any prefix arg will be passed on to
> the selected command.  The default selections are:
>
> a     Call ‘org-agenda-list’ to display the agenda for current day or
> week.

I tried:

```el
(org-agenda "a")
```

and get the same prompt as if I had run `(org-agenda)`. So I don't know how to proceed to the next step of selecting the custom agenda (the "d" after the "a").

How can I call this custom agenda programmatically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to start org-mode agenda with a custom search?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51708/is-there-a-way-to-start-org-mode-agenda-with-a-custom-search)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer in [Is there a way to start org-mode agenda with a custom search?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51708/is-there-a-way-to-start-org-mode-agenda-with-a-custom-search) :

```el
(org-agenda nil "d")
```

Comment: Then why not close the question as a duplicate?

Comment: @NickD I don't have enough reputation to close it and voted to do so. I couldn't find that thread initially with an online search, only after writing the question, therefore I decided to publish this thread.